# Dynamic graph using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, dynamic, range, excel-charts

I have the following table of `SKU` and `Volume` (E4:F10)

| SKU | Volume |
| --- | --- |
| a | 10 |
| b | 20 |
| c | 30 |
| d | 40 |
| e | 50 |
| f | 60 |

I need to make a graph out of this data, with the number of rows determined by a number in E2. For example, if the number in E2 is 4, my graph should only have the SKUs up to c.

My code is as follows:

```
Sub selectVar()
Dim x As Integer

x = Range("f1").Value


ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(201, xlColumnClustered).Select
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("E4" & ":" & "F" & x)

End Sub
```

But I get an error:

> Run-time error '1004'
> Method 'Range' of object'_Global' failed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Why is this error occurring?**

I recreated the data you showed and ran your code.  I got the same error. After clicking the Debug button when the error was thrown, I was directed to the line `ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("E4" & ":" & "F" & x)`.  This line is the first place to check.  I can see that the variable `x` is used, so what is its value? 0.  The variable `x` gets its value from the cell `F1` but there is no data in that cell, so it defaults to the value 0.  So your code is trying to set the source range for the chart to be `E4:F0` which is not possible because there is no cell `F0` so the error is thrown.

**Solution**

You mentioned that cell `E2` is supposed to contain the number of rows that your chart will plot, so the first thing is to change the source of `x` from cell `F1` to cell `E2`.  Assuming that `E2` has the value of 4 like in your example, the range your code will try to use is then `E4:F4` which is not the desired output.  You want 4 rows of data, not the cell on row 4.  Try this for the line to set the source data instead: `ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("E4" & ":" & "F" & x + 4)`  The +4 is added to the value of x because the first row of your range/table is in row 4.  Note that the 4 rows of data here *include the title row* which means that only data rows 5, 6, and 7 will be plotted in this example.

Comment: Thank you. I had misunderstood the offset.